# How to import Alembic Vertex Colors from Houdini correctly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertex-colors, color-management, alembic

I've exported a simple scene from houdini with a few geometries, and written into the vertex colors, Cd, for each mesh a different gray value like:

(.1,.1,.1)(.2,.2,.2) ... etc

When I import this into blender, and use the Attribute node to render in cycles, it seems to be doing some color correction or manipulation of this data (before viewer color transform)..

I get:

(.011) (.031) (.074) etc, it seems to roughly correspond to srgb/lin gamma correction?

I've confirmed by bringing this .abc into maya as well, that the data is written correctly.

How can I disable this? I want the exact numbers I wrote to the geo in houdini.

[image]
[image]

the blender screen shot is taken as I mouse over one of the gray shapes, it should not be .03137